# Designing a Cheap Daily Large Data File Downloading & Database Feeding Job

Tags: database, heroku, architecture, cron

I am currently using Heroku from my web application, and I am currently facing the following design challenge:

Once a day, I have to download large product data files (10 to 20 files of up to 10 MB if GZipped, up to 50 MB otherwise) and feed them to a database, that I would then query for the product search feature of my app, using the users keywords.

Note: the product database can be wiped out / cleaned at every run of the job, the data does not need to be kept. I even think it probably should be discarded, to avoid huge storing costs...

So I need advice on how to design a system that would be able to do just that, using Heroku add-ons, and that would remain "affordable". I would be grateful for suggesting:

- A way to run that downloading / database feeding job (which are
  relatively long running tasks)
- The database engine itself, that would allow to perform fast keyword
  queries for the web application to be "snappy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build this system using the following components:

- [Heroku Postgres Addon (Postgres Database)](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql)
- [Bonsai ElasticSearch Addon (ElasticSearch search engine)](https://addons.heroku.com/bonsai)
- [Heroku Scheduler Addon (scheduled job execution)](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler)
- Ruby on Rails web application
- Tire ElasticSearch client library

You will need to add tables to your Postgres database for the product information you will be storing, this is the authoritative system of record.  You will need to wire up your Rails ActiveRecord models to an ElasticSearch index using the [Tire gem](https://github.com/karmi/retire).  Your web application can run product searches against your ElasticSearch search engine using your ActiveRecord models and the Tire gem integration and pull all details from your Postgres database.

You can right a batch job using Rake to update your application with the latest copy of the product catalog:

1. Download product catalog source files locally
2. Create new copy of tables for each table in product schema
3. Populate temporary tables with new product catalog
4. Drop existing product tables, replace with new table with latest products
5. Rebuild ElasticSearch index of new product catalog

This product update rake task can be scheduled to run every day at an off-peak time (say 3am in the local timezone).

Comment: Thank you Winfield, your answer is very valuable, although I guess I should have given a hint about the platform I am working on, instead of letting you drive me to Ruby on Rails... I am using Perl / Mojolicious, with Cloudant as the backend. Till the time I read your post, I actually saw that Cloudant seems to be providing neat and quick searches, similar to Elastic. Have you already used the Scheduler add-on? I am now focusing on this, and would like to use Perl as the language for my cron jobs...

Comment: OK, I have done much more homework now, and I have found all the tips I needed. These tips are probably off-topic here though, so I will accept your answer as the solution, since it responded well my original questions. Thanks again.